# Python Generator Yield Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I have a function that produces a large amount of data and store them in a dictionary that is to be returned at the end of the function. However I've been told that it's not efficient in terms of memory and that I should use data generator in Python.

Example:

```
def gen_data(dataz):
    data_dict = {"uniqz":[], "random":[]}

    for v in dataz:
        if dataz[v]["row"] == "ay1":
            data_dict["uniqz"].append(dataz[v]["row"])
        else:
            data_dict["random"].append(dataz[v]["val"])

    return data_dict

dataz = {"ax1":{"row":"ay1","val":2},
                "ax2":{"row":"ay2","val":3}}

print(gen_data(dataz))
```

How do I convert this block of code and make use of data generator/yield?

I know how to yield individual dictionary data, example:

```
for i in xrange(num_people):
        datadict = {
                    'id': i
                }
        yield datadict
```

But in the above scenario it should append all necessary data into the dictionary first before yielding. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use the data, from your code above you are creating all the values and processing it at once. generator are useful when you want to process data one at a time (or one batch at a time)

Here you can modify your code like this

```py
def gen_data(dataz):
    for v in dataz:
        if dataz[v]["row"] == "ay1":
            yield ("uniqz", dataz[v]["row"])

        else:
            yield ("random", dataz[v]["val"])
```

then you can process your data like below

```py
for key, value in gen_data(dataz):
    process(key, value)
```

In this way you will save the memory occupied by the dictionary. This will also be efficient in case of parallel processing. e.g. there will be some latency in getting new data and also in processing it, using generator, while you are getting data from some source it can be processed in parallel in different thread or machine

Comment: What if I want the full dictionary data at the code where the function is called?

At the end of the day I am still storing the full data at a variable if I were to get all the results from the yield function, that will occupy the same memory size?

E.g 

Scenario 1:
Store data in dictionary and return it 
vs
Scenario 2:
Yield the datas, get all the values and store in dictionary when it is called.

Comment: ya if you need all data in memory at once then using generator doesn't make sense, but in most of the cases we only need some aggregate values of whole data or we store data to file or send over network in such cases it makes sense. e.g. in case of sending data over network using yield let us send data to process while we are fetching instead of waiting for all data to load before sending